# MySQL UPDATE query not working from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following query string is working from the phpMyAdmin SQL panel, but not from my php script. 
I checked with mysqli_affected_rows()... it returns 0. But from SQL panel it affects particular 1 row.
The user account for the MySQL db I am using from php script has UPDATE privilege set.

```
UPDATE forecast SET forecastAmount = 1000.00, updBy='Admin User', updDt=now() WHERE companyId=2 AND forecastDate='2018-03-01';
```

PHP Script:

```
$forecastDate =  date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST['forecastMonth'], ($i+1), $_POST['forecastYear']))."<br>";
$queryStringForecastUpdate = "UPDATE $tbl_forecast
    SET forecastAmount = ".$_POST['day'][$i].
    ", updBy='".$_SESSION['ssnName'].
    "', updDt=now()".
    " WHERE companyId=".$_POST['forecastCompany'].
    " AND forecastDate='$forecastDate';";
if (mysqli_query($dbConn, $queryStringForecastUpdate)) {
    echo mysqli_affected_rows($dbConn);
    $_SESSION['sccMsg'] = "Updated successfully";
} else {
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Error: " . $queryStringForecastUpdate . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbConn);
}
```

Can anyone pls tell me what might goes wrong here?

Comment: where is `$tbl_forecast` defined? what is the ouput of `$queryStringForecastUpdate`?

Comment: And see about prepared and bound queries

Comment: @SebastianBrosch $tbl_forecast = "forecast" defined earlier in the script. Output of $queryStringForecastUpdate is the SQL statement: "UPDATE forecast SET forecastAmount = 1000.00, updBy='Admin User', updDt=now() WHERE companyId=2 AND forecastDate='2018-03-01';" as stated above.

Comment: Did you try the same query from mysql console? Is it working?  and what is the error in php?

Comment: Your using `($i+1)` for the day in your PHP code, shouldn't it just be `1` as your example uses 1

Comment: @NitinDhomse From SQL console it affects particular 1 row and the result is perfect.

Comment: @IshtiaqAhsan What is the error in php?

Comment: @NigelRen this script is actually inside a for loop... but it works just fine... the output SQL statement is working in the console perfectly.

Comment: @NitinDhomse absolutely no error :( It gets to the if block, shows the affected row as 0 and assigns "Updated successfully" to $_SESSION['sccMsg']... nothing in $_SESSION['errMsg']

Comment: @IshtiaqAhsan Rows affected 0 means your query worked but, no matching case found as per your where clause.

Comment: @NitinDhomse, when I run the SQL output from $queryStringForecastUpdate in the console, it affects 1 row.

Comment: Check for the date condition, Is the date is of type date or varchar? may be date comparison not working properly from php

Comment: the `forcastDate` column is of `date` type.

Answer (score 0):

got the problem: I mistakenly added a `<br>` at the end of `$forecastDate` assignment in line 1.